# Redirect to /admin/auth/user/ since my Django app

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls, django-users

I'm looking for add a new `reverse url` in order to redirect to `/admin/auth/user/` in my Django Admin page.

In my template, I already have : `href="{% url "admin:index" %}"` line which let to overcome to the admin page.

I would like to go directly to the `users manage page` and `groups manage page` respectively `admin/auth/user/` and `admin/auth/group`.

My urls.py file looks like :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name=os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'Accueil/templates/Choice.html')),
        name='choice'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^Identity/', include('Identity.urls')),
    url(r'^Accueil/', include('Accueil.urls')),
    url(r'^Home/', include('log.urls')),
    url(r'^Informations/', include('Informations.urls')), 
    url(r'^Configurations/', include('Configurations.urls')),
    url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

How I can write `href="{% url "admin:index" %}"` in order to add `user` and `group` ? Up to now, I don't find a way to do that.

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reverse the user and group changelist urls with:

```
{% url "admin:auth_user_changelist" %}
{% url "admin:auth_group_changelist" %}
```

See the docs on [reversing admin urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-reverse-urls) for more info.